# Customize Bulma Progress Bar with JS depending on password strength

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, bulma

I am trying to check the password strength with the 'zxcvbn' and so far this only works for text:

```
var zxcvbn = require('zxcvbn')
var strength = {
  0: "very weak",
  1: "pretty weak",
  2: "weak",
  3: "strong",
  4: "very strong"
}

var password = document.getElementById('pass');
var meter = document.getElementsByClassName('.progress');
var text = document.getElementById('password-strength-text');

password.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var val = password.value;
  var result = zxcvbn(val);

if (val !== "") {
    text.innerHTML = "Strength: " + strength[result.score]; 
  } else {
    text.innerHTML = "";
  }
});
```

As you might have guessed I am working with Bulma progress bar here:

```
var meter = document.getElementsByClassName('.progress');
```

Basically this bar has values

```
<progress class="progress" value="15" max="100">15%</progress>
```

How do I access those depending on the password strength? So smth. like this:

```
function updateProgressBar() {
  if (strength[result.score] = 0) {... ??? ...}
```

Or is this a complete wrong way of thinking? It showld work basically as a normal password strength meter, also changing color from red to green. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fugured out how to do this with JQuery. First I need an array of values.

```
var progressArr = [0, 10, 20, 40, 80, 100];

if (strength[result.score] == "weak" {
$('.progress').val(20).addClass('is-danger')};
```

Then just going down with all the values and else if statements.